# Nuxt - override default document with custom app.html

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

The Nuxt docs [say](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views#document-apphtml) you can override the default document by...

> creating an `app.html` file in the source directory of your project which by default is the root directory.

I did just that. I created the following `app.html` in my project root:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    <script>alert('custom document');</script>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Note the `alert()`, which is just to confirm it's using the custom document.

When I serve the project it continues to use the default document, however. The docs don't say you have to do anything else to enable the custom document, other than create the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Working perfectly fine on my side.

### [image]

[image]

I'm using `target: static` and `ssr: false` (works with `ssr: true` too).

The issue should be coming from somewhere else. Like a middleware or alike.

Comment: Interestingly, I found I had to restart Nuxt via `npm run dev`. I found this by accident after a config parse error forced the server to stop and had to be restarted. It now loads my custom doc.